# Node js throw error about strict mode although using babel 6 preset es2015 with contains strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

node js throw this error `uncaughtException: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode` although I'm using babel 6 es2015 present that suppose to add `use strict`.

I have `.babelrc` file exist and this is how I instantiate babel:

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
    retainLines: true
});
```

Furthermore, when I use babel CLI to see the output files they have `use strict`

Am I missing something?

**
EDIT: Is it possible node js doesn't use the output of babel?

Comment: Babel is not using the preset. If it was, there wouldn't be any let/const/class in your code for it to complain about.

Comment: I also tried to add "presets": ["es2015"] next to retainLines and it still gives me that error

Comment: Are you using es6 code in the script that does the transforming? it doesn't transform itself you know.

Comment: No, you can see the part of the code that execute the transforming in my question

Comment: Yes but you didn't give us the entire script, if there is a let in the script *doing* the transforming it will fail.

Comment: I'm not using any script... can you please explain what you mean? * I just edited my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116101/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-rotem).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I changed

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
    retainLines: true
});
```

to

```
require("babel-core/register");
```

and configured all the options in the `.babelrc` file

What weird is that this (what I initially did) appear in babel documentation (https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)